# GridLayout wrong positioning

Tags: python, kivy

I have my simple python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


Builder.load_file('Matrixkivy.kv') 
 
class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MatrixCalc(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MatrixCalc().run()
```

And simple .kv code:

```
<MyLayout>
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text: "Button1"
        Button:
            text: "Button2"
```

I want to get a GridLayout which is of size of the entire app and two buttons, which both take half of it. However, app displays all things that the app contain in the bottom left corner. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main  problem is that you are using the base `Widget` class as a container. You can do that, but the `Layout` classes already have the code to handle things like `size_hint` and `pos_hint`. One fix for your code is to replace:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
```

with:

```
class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

You should also remove the line:

```
size_hint: root.width, root.height
```

`Size_hint` values should be numbers typically in the range `0-1`. And add a line that defines either `rows` or `cols` for the `GridLayout`, so your `kv` could look like:

```
<MyLayout>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: "Button1"
        Button:
            text: "Button2"
```

Since you are using `GridLayout` as a child of `MyLayout`, you can just make `MyLayout` extend `GridLayout`, and then you can eliminate the `GridLayout` line from your `kv`. With this approach, your `MyLayout` class would look like:

```
class MyLayout(GridLayout):
    pass
```

and the corresponding `kv`:

```
<MyLayout>
    cols: 1
    Button:
        text: "Button1"
    Button:
        text: "Button2"
```